# Regular expression needed for PHP preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need help with a regular expression in PHP.
I have one string containing a lot of data and the format could be like this.

`key=value,e4354ahj\,=awet3,asdfa\=asdfa=23f23`

So I have 2 delimiters , and = where , is the set of key and value. The thing is that key and value can contain the same symbols , and = but they will always be escaped. So I cant use explode. I need to use preg_split but I am no good at regular expressions.

Could someone give me a hand with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
// 4 backslashes because they are in a PHP string, so PHP translates them to \\
// and then the regex engine translates the \\ to a literal \
$keyValuePairs = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\),/', $input);
```

This will split on every `,` that is not escaped, so you get key-value pairs. You can do the same for each pair to separate the key and value:

```
list($key, $value) = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\)=/', $pair);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/s5PEQx)**.

Answer (score 1):

@Jon's answer is awesome. I though of providing a solution by matching the string:

```
preg_match_all('#(.*?)(?<!\\\\)=(.*?)(?:(?<!\\\\),|$)#', $string, $m);
// You'll find the keys in $m[1] and the values in $m[2]
$array = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [key] => value
    [e4354ahj\,] => awet3
    [asdfa\=asdfa] => 23f23
)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(.*?)(?<!\\\\)=` : match anything and group it until `=` not preceded by `\`
- `(.*?)(?:(?<!\\\\),|$)` : match anything and group it until `,` not preceded by `\` or end of line.

Comment: This works fine and is convenient, nice touch. The only drawback is that code like this must be accompanied by generous amounts of comments.

Comment: @Jon I was writing a `preg_split` solution but you were faster :-)